# Rails partial html escape

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view

Im trying to escape some text in rails but I want to replace newlines with html breaks:

```
text = "Hi\n<b>there</b><i>italic</i>\nNewline"
```

I simply use

```
<%=text.gsub(/\n/, "<br/>") %>
```

But this will give me `Hi<br/><b>there</b><i>italic</i><br/>Newline` as my actual output.

What im looking for is (as would be seen in the browser)

```
Hi
<b>there</b>
<i>italic</i>
Newline
```

How would I partially escape (I only want to replace line breaks but all the other html I'd like escaped)

Comment: Escape first, then add the line breaks?

Comment: Is there a function to escape?

Comment: did you try `simple_format` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

First replace `<` with `&lt;` to escape existing HTML, then replace `\n` with `<br />` as you are currently doing.

Comment: Will this still be safe with all the other characters?

Comment: Without `<`, there is no possible parsing of HTML (assuming you aren't dumping this into an attribute or `<script>` block), so it's all you need to do to make it inert. That said, if you also want entities to remain as they are, you should also replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use HTML pre tag here..

This should display whatever you have asked..

```
text = "<pre>Hi\n<b>there</b><i>italic</i>\nNewline</pre>"
<%= text %>
```